# WIF Ntier Authentication

Tags: .net, n-tier-architecture, wif

I have a basic 3 tier app

- Presentation/Web (ASP.NET MVC)
- Application Services (WCF, hosted in IIS)
- Database (SQL)

I am trying to authenticate the user against any and all tiers using WIF. At the moment I have authenticated the user against the Web (MVC).

**How do I pass the users token through to the next teir?**

PS I am using the "StarterSTS" project you can find on Codeplex.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original user identity on the WCF services, then your web site will have to request a token to an STS on behalf of that user. The input for requesting an "Act As" token is the orignal token sent to the 1st tier (the MVC app). Not all STSs support the "ActAs" request, so you need to double check that.

There are examples in the [Identity Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3e315fa-94e2-4028-99cb-904369f177c0)